# Drupal index.php

Tags: drupal, include

I've had to pick up a web app built with Drupal - I need to edit a link that is on the front end. It is a single page app - but when I open index.php there is a link to a bootstrap.inc which contains over 11000 lines of code none of which relate to the front end.

Comment: Do you mean the link is in the theme?

Comment: Haha didn;t think of looking in the themes folder, solved the issues now wast in themes/theme-name/templates :)

Comment: There's no actual question here. Are you asking what index.php does? How do edit a link? How bootstrap.inc works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal, `index.php` is a router. It gets a request from the server, with the path added to it. It then routes the request through many (complex) layers to create the HTML.

I suggest you read up on the basics of Drupal before diving head-first into the application.

Based on your question, you seem to completely misunderstand the basics of Drupals routing, to beging with.

- Request /foo/bar arrives at Apache
- Apache calls `index.php?q=foo/bar
- Drupal gets bootstrapped.
- Drupal loads the menu-system.
- Drupal looks up, if there is a [menu-router](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) to handle "foo/bar". Or one of the parents to fall back on ("foo" in this case).
- If found, Drupal will call the callback for that page: for example my_bar.module implements hook_menu and registers "foo/bar" with callback `my_bar_page`. This function is available in this module.
- `my_bar_page` is called. Its output should be HTML.
- Drupal loads the theme layer, and passes the received HTML as $content into the [page template](https://drupal.org/node/1089642). (amongst others, it also loads the block system, adds footers and does loads of complex preprocessing on all the page variables).

Note that this is a very much simplified version of what actually goes on. The reality is a gigantic (spaggetti, some might say) of callbacks, caching layers, hooks and theme-layers.

Comment: See also http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/living-breathing-drupal-biology-request to understand what's happening and how Drupal handlers a request.

Answer (score -1):

A link on the front-end would be changed in the theme. There is no need to touch index.php. There are a number of places in the theme where this might be edited. A good place to start looking is /admin/structure/block.